# Balance Check: Monsters Team Work

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I was thinking about an optional monster rule to make an encounter with more creatures fighting in the same space as a "Team Work". This would help adding more creatures in one combat reducing the number of rolls.

The idea is to "combo" some stats and make some of them work by each creature.

Here's what I thought so far:

Team Work:

Creatures of medium size or smaller with identical stat blocks can start combat fighting together as Team Work, occupying the same space on the battle grid. Creatures must be within 5 feet of each other at the time of initiative and in their first turn them move to the same space where one of the creatures is already located, this movement consumes 5 feet of movement or double if the terrain is difficult. Their initiative is rolled only once, and they act as if they were a single creature. At the start of each of their turns they can decide to separate their initiatives, in doing so they disperse, each one in an individual space.

**Damage**: Creatures are treated as a single creature, except for area attacks, whose damage is multiplied by the number of creatures fighting together.

**HP**: The HP of each creature is added together to define the total HP.

**Dying**: When creatures fighting together receive enough damage to kill one of them, the GM must decide which one dies and rearrange the attack and damage attributes of the team of creatures that remain in the group.

**Single-target effects**: If the group receives an effect that is against a single target that prevents it from acting together with the rest of the group, the others can choose to separate from the affected creature at the start of their next or fight in the same space, but without adding the affected creature's damage/effect attributes when performing its actions.

**Multi-target effects**: Each group member must make a saving throw. The rules for splitting up in case part of the party becomes incapacitated follow those of “Single Target Effects”.

**Actions**: When performing actions, creatures perform a single action and, when dealing damage, this is multiplied by the number of creatures in the group in case of hit.

Although it seems complicated, I believe that this mechanic can facilitate the GM's work and make the combats more dynamic since the GM can use many creatures in a single combat without increasing so much the number of actions and deciding to separate the group of creatures when a part of the other creatures in combat have already fallen.

Is it balanced? Is there any extra information I need to address?

Comment: Is the intent here that all the monsters in a group are identical? You didn't say that. I can see doing this for a troop of baboons or a horde of goblins, but it doesn't make any sense if you're grouping up like a Goblin Sergeant and a Drow Assassin. Their actions would be all over the place.

Comment: Oh! That was the point. I must have erased the information at some point while preparing the text. It is supposed to be for creatures with the same stat block.

Answer (score 11):

### This already exists

The DMG has section on page 250 about using "Mobs", which involves combining multiple monsters into a single action and determining hits as if they'd all rolled on a regular distribution instead of actually throwing dice. There are good and bad things about the optional Mob rules (personally I dislike how predictable it makes the monsters).

### Playing all the hits

I think the big problem you're going to run into very quickly with your rule set is that this makes a group of monsters much more deadly than they otherwise would be. Or rather, it makes the group more *swingy*, which usually translates to deadly.

Let us assume you have a group of four goblins, and they are attacking a first level fighter, who has 14 HP and kills a goblin every round without fail. The goblins have a 33% chance to hit the fighter and deal 5 damage on a hit.

In the first round, the fighter takes one hit, he's at 9 HP.  He kills a goblin.
In the second round, the fighter takes one hit, he's at 4 HP. He kills a goblin.

So now there are two goblins left, but the fighter can't take another hit. There's a high chance he'll take a hit, but it's possible they'll both miss him. He needs to start making some tactical decisions.

Now let's make them a group.
In the first round, the goblins roll once, miss, and the fighter takes out one one them.
In the second round, the goblins roll a hit, deal 15 damage, and the fighter is down.

The fact that four goblins make four rolls means they're very likely to get close to the average number of hits -- it's POSSIBLE to roll a 15+ four times running, but it's not likely. Reducing that to one all-or-nothing roll means the goblins are not likely to hit, but when they do it's devastating, and more importantly the player didn't get a chance to react.  They went from full HP to unconscious in a single turn, and that's just not fun for the player.

Comment: I think the extra effort of just rolling e.g. 4 dice at once and count how many are hits is minimal. and then just say to the player "2 goblins hit for 5 damage each"

Comment: Thanks about the info from DMG. I'll take a look on it.
About the deadly thing I know it can happen, but the objetive here is to use weak monsters in group to be able to make a lot of monsters in a fight against a party.
Imagine 20 goblins from the tribe fighting a party of 4 level 3 players. The Team Work would be good to make it "five" enemies, and after some monsters are dead the GM can split the team work groups to keep it with around 5 enemies.

Comment: Falco, that's a good idea too. Make them together to help on initiative, but roll attack dice all together. That would solve the problem for high damage in one attack roll.